# Issue with Radial Gradients in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to reproduce the gradient demo given here
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMXGradient_(Delphi)

I've copied everything exactly and have debugged to confirm that the functions are getting called. The linear gradient works fine. However, the radial gradient doesn't change when I set RotationCenter.X or RotationCenter.Y as shown on the web page. I get no change. However, I do get a change when I change RotationAngle. I've noticed previously that setting RotationCenter in a TTransform appears to do nothing. Looking at the TTransform class in FMX.Types I see that RotationCenter isn't used at all. I'm using Delphi 10.4 Sydney. Is this a change in the code that's crept in since the demo on the web page was created?

I've tried setting TTransform.Position instead of RotationCenter since I can see that it gets used. However that doesn't seem to do anything either and I can see in FMX.Types that SetPosition isn't calling MatrixChanged(). In summary it seems broken to me or at least different from the demo. Can anyone else confirm and suggest how I can get it working?

unit source

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Colors, FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Ellipse1: TEllipse;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ListBoxItem1: TListBoxItem;
    ListBoxItem2: TListBoxItem;
    ColorComboBox1: TColorComboBox;
    ColorComboBox2: TColorComboBox;
    procedure ColorComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ColorComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit2Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit3Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit4Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBoxItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBoxItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.ColorComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ellipse1.Visible then
    Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Color := ColorComboBox1.Color
  else
    Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.Color := ColorComboBox1.Color;
end;

procedure TForm1.ColorComboBox2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ellipse1.Visible then
    Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Color1 := ColorComboBox2.Color
  else
    Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.Color1 := ColorComboBox2.Color;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ellipse1.Visible then
    Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.RotationAngle :=
      StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)
  else
    Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StartPosition.X := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ellipse1.Visible then
    Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.RotationCenter.X :=
      StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)
  else
    Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StartPosition.Y := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit3Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ellipse1.Visible then
    Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.RotationCenter.Y :=
      StrToFloat(Edit3.Text)
  else
    Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.X := StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit4Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.Y := StrToFloat(Edit4.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ellipse1.Visible := False;
  Rectangle1.Visible := False;

  // Fill initialization so Gradient can be applied
  Ellipse1.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Gradient;
  Rectangle1.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Gradient;

  Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Radial;
  Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Linear;
  Label1.Text := 'Choose the gradient type';
  ListBoxItem1.Text := 'Linear';
  ListBoxItem2.Text := 'Radial';
  Label2.Text := '';
  Label3.Text := '';
  Label4.Text := '';
  Label5.Text := '';
  Edit1.Visible := False;
  Edit2.Visible := False;
  Edit3.Visible := False;
  Edit4.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ComboBox1.Selected.Text = 'Linear' then ListBoxItem1Click(Self) else
  if ComboBox1.Selected.Text = 'Radial' then ListBoxItem2Click(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label2.Text := 'StartPosition.X: ';
  Label3.Text := 'StartPosition.Y: ';
  Label4.Text := 'StopPosition.X: ';
  Label5.Text := 'StopPosition.Y: ';
  Edit1.Visible := True;
  Edit2.Visible := True;
  Edit3.Visible := True;
  Edit4.Visible := True;
  Ellipse1.Visible := False;
  Rectangle1.Visible := True;

  // Set the Gradient colors
  Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.Color1 := ColorComboBox2.Color;
  Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.Color := ColorComboBox1.Color;
  // Populate the Edit Boxes
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StartPosition.X);
  Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StartPosition.Y);
  Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.X);
  Edit4.Text := FloatToStr(Rectangle1.Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label2.Text := 'RotationAngle:';
  Label3.Text := 'RotationCenter.X:';
  Label4.Text := 'RotationCenter.Y:';
  Label5.Text := '';
  Edit1.Visible := True;
  Edit2.Visible := True;
  Edit3.Visible := True;
  Edit4.Visible := False;
  Ellipse1.Visible := True;
  Rectangle1.Visible := False;

  // Set the Gradient colors
  Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Color1 := ColorComboBox2.Color;
  Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Color := ColorComboBox1.Color;

  // Populate the edit boxes
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.
    RotationAngle);
  Edit2.Text := FloatToStr(Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.
    RotationCenter.X);
  Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform.
    RotationCenter.Y);

end;

end.
```

form source

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Position.X = 184.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 449.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 465.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Ellipse1: TEllipse
    Position.X = 184.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 449.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 465.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 24.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 177.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Choose the gradient type'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 208.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label2'
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 264.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label3'
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 312.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label4'
  end
  object Label5: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 368.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Label5'
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 224.000000000000000000
    OnChange = Edit1Change
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 280.000000000000000000
    OnChange = Edit2Change
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 336.000000000000000000
    OnChange = Edit3Change
  end
  object Edit4: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 392.000000000000000000
    OnChange = Edit4Change
  end
  object ComboBox1: TComboBox
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 72.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    OnChange = ComboBox1Change
    object ListBoxItem1: TListBoxItem
      Text = 'ListBoxItem1'
      OnClick = ListBoxItem1Click
    end
    object ListBoxItem2: TListBoxItem
      Text = 'ListBoxItem2'
      OnClick = ListBoxItem2Click
    end
  end
  object ColorComboBox1: TColorComboBox
    DropDownKind = Custom
    Color = claNull
    DisableFocusEffect = False
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 112.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    OnChange = ColorComboBox1Change
  end
  object ColorComboBox2: TColorComboBox
    DropDownKind = Custom
    Color = claNull
    DisableFocusEffect = False
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 144.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    OnChange = ColorComboBox2Change
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you make the project source available somewhere so that I can check quickly without recreating the sample? If you do, edit your question with the link.

Comment: The project source is on the web page I linked to. The only thing missing is the form. I could include my form code in the question. I don't know where I would host my code.

Comment: Thanks. I created a bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31476

Comment: Thanks. So I assume that you observed the same behaviour? It looks like an issue with TTransform to me. How long does it normally take for these kind of things to get resolved?

Comment: How do I sign in to the quality link you gave? It says to contact the JIRA administrators. Should anyone with a registered product be able to sign in? I have a professional license.

Comment: You use the same Login credentials that you use for rest of Embarcadero-s web pages..

Comment: Would I have received a login when I registered? I did receive a serial number with a login name, but no password. Whatever I do I don't seem to be able to login.

Comment: I've now found a workaround for the radial transform issue until it gets fixed. I compute the TTransform matrix myself and set it using a hack to set a private member. Not an ideal solution but there doesn't seem to be an alternative.


  TTransformHack = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMatrix: TMatrix;
  end;


  TTransformHack(Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.RadialTransform).FMatrix := LMatrix;
  Ellipse1.Fill.Gradient.Change;

Comment: "Would I have received a login when I registered? " That's the reverse: you had to create a login to register. Goto https://edn.embarcadero.com/ if you forgot the password you used to register, just click "forgot password".